# GetAll private member ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection, zend-framework2

Is there a way to list all private member of an instance with `Zend\Server\Reflection`?

[The documentation for this class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.server.reflection.html) is very light 
I can't get any way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is using [php `ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) internally. You can do like this:

```
$reflection = \Zend\Server\Reflection::reflectClass($className);
$properties = $reflection->getProperties();
$propertyNames = array();
foreach($properties as $property){
    if($property->isPrivate()){
        $propertyNames[] = $property->getName();
    }
}
var_dump($propertyNames);
```

I tested in ZF2 version 2.5.1 and there it works...

Comment: I had to put this flag ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE in getProperties
And 
  $prop->setAccessible( true );
  $prop->getValue($obj));
  $prop->setAccessible( false );

and set as public to access to the value. 

But your solution worked, could you edit it please

Comment: @ChristopheDebove I tested once more and it works without the extra code for me.  I added version number instead, so your comment should be enough to help other people if it doesn't work for them.